# Control what is returned by methods of a class in Python

Tags: python, abstract-class

My goal is to create a bunch of (derived) classes that return the same structured data/variables when their primary "run" method is called. In other words, when the run method is called, it must return "a, b, c, d, e, f, g" and so on.

To demonstrate, I came up with an example of a game where the base class is `Enemy` and two possible subclasses are `Kobold` and `Crow`. The main "run" method is `do_battle` and the result of this battle must return `player_hp_lost` and `gold_dropped` as well as any extra information that is stored in `other`.

Here it is in code

```
import abc                                                                                                                                                                                   
from typing import Dict                                                                                                                                                                      

class Enemy(abc.ABC):                                                                                                                                                                        
    def __init__(self, health: int, armor: int):                                                                                                                                             
        self.health                                                                                                                                                                          
        self.armor                                                                                                                                                                           

    def generate_battle_results(self,                                                                                                                                                        
                                player_hp_lost: int,                                                                                                                                         
                                loot_dropped: int,                                                                                                                                           
                                other: Dict):                                                                                                                                                
        battle_results = {                                                                                                                                                                   
            "player_hp_lost": player_hp_lost,                                                                                                                                                
            "gold_dropped": loot_dropped,                                                                                                                                                    
            "other": other                                                                                                                                                                   
            }                                                                                                                                                                                

    @abc.abstractmethod                                                                                                                                                                      
    def do_battle(self)                                                                                                                                                                      


class Kobold(Enemy)                                                                                                                                                                            
    def __init__(self, rage_level: int, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                    
        self.rage_level = rage_level                                                                                                                                                         
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                    

    def do_battle(self):                                                                                                                                                                     
        # some convoluted logic that results in player hp lost, loot dropped, etc                                                                                                            
        player_hp_lost = 5                                                                                                                                                                   
        gold_dropped = 0                                                                                                                                                                     
        other = {"time taken to finish battle": 10,                                                                                                                                          
                 "fun had": 2                                                                                                                                                                
        }                                                                                                                                                                                    

        return self.generate_battle_results(player_hp_lost=player_hp_lost,                                                                                                                   
                                            gold_dropped=gold_dropped,                                                                                                                       
                                            other=other)                                                                                                                                     

def Crow(Enemy)                                                                                                                                                                              
    def __init__(self, num_feathers: int, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                  
        self.num_feathers = num_feathers                                                                                                                                                     
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                    

    def do_battle(self):                                                                                                                                                                     
        # some convoluted logic that results in player hp lost, loot dropped, etc                                                                                                            
        player_hp_lost = 3                                                                                                                                                                   
        gold_dropped = 1                                                                                                                                                                     
        other = {"kaw kaws before death": 10,                                                                                                                                                
                 "estimated annoyance factor":6                                                                                                                                              
        }                                                                                                                                                                                    

        return self.generate_battle_results(player_hp_lost=player_hp_lost,                                                                                                                   
                                            gold_dropped=gold_dropped,                                                                                                                       
                                            other=other)
```

In the above example, I want `do_battle` to always return `player_hp_lost` and `gold_dropped`. However, note that a user can create a new subclass of `Enemy` and not call `self.generate_battle_results` and return a dict of his own choosing, which is what I want to avoid.  Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Maybe a typo, but `def Kobold(Enemy)` should actually be `class Kobold(Enemy):`

Answer (score 1):

You could define a concrete `do_battle` that calls `generate_battle_results`, then require that the user implement some other method that returns the values that be fed to that method.

```
class Enemy:
    ...
    def do_battle(self):
        return self.generate_battle_results(**self.simulate_combat())
    @abstractmethod
    def simulate_combat(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

Now the `simulate_combat` method has to return a dict containing those 3 values, or the call to `generate_battle_results` will complain about missing arguments.

Note that a sufficiently motivated programmer using this module can still override `do_battle` or `generate_battle_results` and make them do whatever they want.  This is fine. As long as your code is clear and easy to use, it's okay if other people want to modify it later on to suit their own purposes.

Answer (score 0):

> However, note that a user can create a new subclass of `Enemy` and not call `self.generate_battle_results` and return a dict of his own choosing, which is what I want to avoid.

The one who gonna use your code can do much more. For example, user can create his own class without using `Enemy` class at all. I mean user can do literally anything without worrying about what you want. I guess it is true for any programming language especially if source code is available.

> Is there any way to do that?

I believe it is impossible in Python.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to offer a method that subclasses can override, and wrap that method into another one in the parent class to check for errors:

```
class Enemy(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self, health: int, armor: int):
        self.health = health
        self.armor = armor

    def do_battle(self):
        data = self.subclass_do_battle()

        # check that all mandatory parts are present
        for k in ('player_hp_lost', 'gold_dropped'):
            # this may raise KeyError
            _ = data[k]

        return data

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def subclass_do_battle(self):
        return {}

class Kobold(Enemy):
    def __init__(self, rage_level: int, *args, **kwargs):
        self.rage_level = rage_level
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def subclass_do_battle(self):
        # some convoluted logic that results in player hp lost, loot dropped, etc

        return {
            'player_hp_lost': 5,
            'gold_dropped': 0,
            'time taken to finish battle': 10,
            'fun had': 2,
        }

class Crow(Enemy):
    def __init__(self, num_feathers: int, *args, **kwargs):
        self.num_feathers = num_feathers
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def subclass_do_battle(self):
        # some convoluted logic that results in player hp lost, loot dropped, etc

        return {
            'player_hp_lost': 5,
            'gold_dropped': 0,
            'kaw kaws before death': 9,
            'estimated annoyance factor': 6,
        }
```

As you can see, subclasses should only implement `Enemy.subclass_do_battle()` and the parent class `Enemy.do_battle()` will call the implemented subclass method and check the return data before returning it to the final caller.

And there is no way to avoid anyone overriding the method `Enemy.do_battle()`. In `Python` we usually work under the pretext that we are all consenting adults; this language is not designed so that you can make methods private like in other languages (for example `Java`).